# PL/SQL with INSERT new data to table with validation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Created a simple PL/sql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Insert_Invoice(
    inv_number IN NUMBER,
    cust_id IN NUMBER,
    date_in DATE,
    date_out DATE,
    Sub_tot IN NUMBER,
    tax IN NUMBER,
    total IN NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES( inv_number, cust_id, date_in,date_out,
                             Sub_tot,tax,total);
COMMIT;
END Insert_Invoice;
```

I having an error that ORA-06550 at line1, column 7
PLS-00201,indentifier 'INSERT_INVOICE' must be declared
but i following the example at website but it's still doesn't work. isn't my structure problem?

Comment: Your code compiles and works as expected. Please post your *real* code that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen the procedure name on the `end` statement in PL/SQL.  Try putting it in a comment:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES( inv_number, cust_id, date_in,date_out,
                             Sub_tot,tax,total);
COMMIT;
END;  -- Insert_Invoice
```

Comment: the bottom 1 already got end insert_invoice isn't?

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's strange. For me (11gR2), it works with the procedure name on the end statement (as expected).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt . . . That is good to know.  I put the procedure name as a comment, because other versions of SQL do not allow tagged `end`s, so I just haven't tried this in Oracle.